# Different results from distinct count and select distinct queries

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT distinct COUNT(s.title) as total_tags 
  FROM products s 
 INNER JOIN products_vt vt on vt.pruduct_id=s.id 
 where s.deleted!=1 
   AND vt.positives<5 
   AND (s.title like '%neon pictures free screensaver%' 
         OR s.title LIKE 'neon%' 
         OR s.title LIKE '%neon' 
         OR s.title LIKE '%neon%' 
         OR s.title LIKE 'pictures%' 
         OR s.title LIKE '%pictures' 
         OR s.title LIKE '%pictures%' 
         OR s.title LIKE 'free%' 
         OR s.title LIKE '%free' 
         OR s.title LIKE '%free%' 
         OR s.title LIKE 'screensaver%' 
         OR s.title LIKE '%screensaver' 
         OR s.title LIKE '%screensaver%' ) 
 ORDER by s.title like '%neon pictures free screensaver%' desc , 
          s.title LIKE 'neon%' desc , 
          s.title LIKE '%neon' desc , 
          s.title LIKE '%neon%' desc , 
          s.title LIKE 'pictures%' desc , 
          s.title LIKE '%pictures' desc , 
          s.title LIKE '%pictures%' desc , 
          s.title LIKE 'free%' desc , 
          s.title LIKE '%free' desc , 
          s.title LIKE '%free%' desc , 
          s.title LIKE 'screensaver%' desc , 
          s.title LIKE '%screensaver' desc , 
          s.title LIKE '%screensaver%' desc
```

> Result: 2549

```
SELECT distinct(s.title), 
       s.date_updated, 
       s.title, 
       s.id, 
       s.icon, 
       s.downloads, 
       s.date, 
       s.date_updated, 
       s.version, 
       s.description80, 
       s.downloads,
       s.views,
       s.type, 
       s.platform, 
       s.rating_users,
       vt.positives, 
       vt.total, 
       vt.permalink, 
       vt.scan_date, 
       s.keywords 
  FROM products s 
 INNER JOIN products_vt vt on vt.pruduct_id=s.id 
 where s.deleted!=1 
   AND vt.positives<5 
   AND (s.title like '%neon pictures free screensaver%' 
         OR s.title LIKE 'neon%' 
         OR s.title LIKE '%neon' 
         OR s.title LIKE '%neon%' 
         OR s.title LIKE 'pictures%' 
         OR s.title LIKE '%pictures' 
         OR s.title LIKE '%pictures%' 
         OR s.title LIKE 'free%' 
         OR s.title LIKE '%free' 
         OR s.title LIKE '%free%' 
         OR s.title LIKE 'screensaver%' 
         OR s.title LIKE '%screensaver' 
         OR s.title LIKE '%screensaver%' ) 
 ORDER by s.title like '%neon pictures free screensaver%' desc , 
          s.title LIKE 'neon%' desc , 
          s.title LIKE '%neon' desc , 
          s.title LIKE '%neon%' desc , 
          s.title LIKE 'pictures%' desc , 
          s.title LIKE '%pictures' desc , 
          s.title LIKE '%pictures%' desc , 
          s.title LIKE 'free%' desc , 
          s.title LIKE '%free' desc , 
          s.title LIKE '%free%' desc , 
          s.title LIKE 'screensaver%' desc , 
          s.title LIKE '%screensaver' desc , 
          s.title LIKE '%screensaver%' desc
```

> Result: 2492

Comment: Your search condition (and order by clause) is overly complicated and can be shortened to `...and (s.title LIKE '%neon%' OR s.title LIKE '%pictures%' OR s.title LIKE '%free%' OR s.title LIKE '%screensaver%')`.

Comment: Also I don't see the use of your order-by clauses. I wonder why they don't rise syntax errors but guess they are evaluated as booleans and eventually yield `order by false,false,false,true,false,false,...` or something similar. If you want to order by title, simply do so: `order by s.title desc`. Full stop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think either query is structured correctly. If you want the count of distinct titles then the first query should be:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT s.title) as total_tags...
```

If you want a list of distinct titles then you need to eliminate the other rows from the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.title as total_tags...
```

Answer (score 0):

A query like the first one will count all the records and give output, and it won't give count for distinct values.
`SELECT distinct COUNT(s.title)`
(the first operation will be the count, then distinct).

The second query output will be the distinct values instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers, I resolved it by using `GROUP BY` instead of `SELECT DISTINCT` in second query.